# Show the accumulator result after use houghcircles opencv function

Tags: opencv, image-processing, hough-transform, accumulator

Please I want to draw accumulator output for opencv hougcircles function. .
The function run ok and  detected the  circle (center&radius) only I want to show the accumulator for this function

The path for function 
Opencv\modules\imgprocs\src\hough.cpp
The function name for hough circle icvHoughCirclesGradient the parameter for accumulator is "accum".

Any help please
Thanks

Comment: Firstly, are you spamming SOwith this question? Secondly, what do you mean by "draw accumulator output for opencv houghcircles function"? "accum" seems to be a cv::Mat, then use cv::imshow("title", accum) to display it.

Comment: I am sorry for this. My internet connection is slow.i want to show the accum result after detected circle .I try imshow for accum but found error message 'cv::imshow' : cannot convert parameter 2 from 'cv::Ptr<_Tp>' to 'cv::InputArray'.any help thanks

Comment: uhm, maybe cv::imshow(cv::Mat(accum)); works?

Comment: Thank you for helping me. I try use imshow ("acuum  ",Mat (accum)); work but output is zero image . also try to cout《Mat (accum) the result value not more than 30 value . add some value to accum in order to value reach above 200 to show it but also black image in output of accum

Comment: I suggest you update your question to add details of what you've got, such as the value of accum, the code to produce the accum mat, and the image of accum, and reformulate your question.