# OpenCV+python: HoughLines accumulator access since 3.4.2

Tags: python, opencv, hough-transform

In OpenCV 3.4.2 the option to return the number of votes (accumulator value) for each line returned by HoughLines() was added. In python this seems to be supported as well as read in the python docstring of my OpenCV installation:

> "Each line is represented by a 2 or 3 element vector (*ρ*, *θ*) or (*ρ*, *θ*, *votes*) ."

It is also included in the [docs](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.2/dd/d1a/group__imgproc__feature.html#ga46b4e588934f6c8dfd509cc6e0e4545a) (with some broken formatting).
**However I can find no way to return the 3 element option (*ρ*, *θ*, *votes*) in python.**
Here is code demonstrating the problem:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
print('OpenCV should be at least 3.4.2 to test: ', cv2.__version__)
image = np.eye(10, dtype='uint8')
lines = cv2.HoughLines(image, 1, np.pi/180, 5)
print('(number of lines, 1, output vector dimension): ', lines.shape)
print(lines)
```

outputs

```
OpenCV should be at least 3.4.2 to test:  3.4.2
(number of lines, 1, output vector dimension):  (3, 1, 2)
[[[ 0.         2.3212879]]

 [[ 1.         2.2340214]]

 [[-1.         2.4609141]]]
```

The desired behavior is an extra column with the amount of votes each line received. With the vote values more advanced options than the standard thresholding can be applied, as such it has been often requested and asked about on SE ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3265987/opencv-get-hough-accumulator-value), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11352528/opencv-hough-strongest-lines), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31543444/access-to-hough-transform-accumulator) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28718956/show-the-accumulator-result-after-use-houghcircles-opencv-function)) with sometimes the equivalent for HoughCircles(). However both the questions and answers (such as modifying source and recompiling) are from before it was added officially, and therefore do not apply to the current situation.

Comment: OpenCV 4.3.2 does not exist... work on 4.0 is still in progress. The most recent release is 3.4.3.

Comment: @Dan Mašek Edited the typo. 4.3.2 -> 3.4.2.

Comment: Looking at [the code](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/9787ab598b6609a6ca6652a12441d741cb15f695/modules/imgproc/src/hough.cpp#L900), the way to get the votes (at least in C++) is to provide an `OutputArray` that has fixed type, specifically one equivalent to `CV_32FC3`. I think that would be an instance wrapping a `cv::Mat3f`, for example. At this point, I'm quite doubtful you can pass something that satisfies the criteria from Python, but I'll try to poke around a bit.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As of vanilla OpenCV 3.4.3, you can't use this functionality from Python.

## How it Works in C++

First of all in the [implementation of `HoughLines`](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/9787ab598b6609a6ca6652a12441d741cb15f695/modules/imgproc/src/hough.cpp#L901), we can see code that selects the type of the output array `lines`:

```
int type = CV_32FC2;
if (lines.fixedType())
{
    type = lines.type();
    CV_CheckType(type, type == CV_32FC2 || type == CV_32FC3, "Wrong type of output lines");
}
```

We can then see this parameter used in [implementation of `HoughLinesStandard`](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/9787ab598b6609a6ca6652a12441d741cb15f695/modules/imgproc/src/hough.cpp#L207) when populating `lines`:

```
if (type == CV_32FC2)
{
    _lines.at<Vec2f>(i) = Vec2f(line.rho, line.angle);
}
else
{
    CV_DbgAssert(type == CV_32FC3);
    _lines.at<Vec3f>(i) = Vec3f(line.rho, line.angle, (float)accum[idx]);
}
```

Similar code can be seen [in `HoughLinesSDiv`](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/9787ab598b6609a6ca6652a12441d741cb15f695/modules/imgproc/src/hough.cpp#L444).

Based on this, we need to pass in an `_OutputArray` that is **fixed type**, and stores 32bit floats in 3 channels. How to make a fixed type (but not fixed size, since the algorithm needs to be able to resize it) `_OutputArray`? Let's look at the [implementation](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/d74b98c3d9264f9623b27a8d4e0fc92ac97b71d0/modules/core/include/opencv2/core/mat.inl.hpp#L188) again:

- A generic `cv::Mat` is not fixed type, neither is `cv::UMat`
- One option is `std::vector<cv::Vec3f>`
- Another option is `cv::Mat3f` (that's a `cv::Matx<_Tp, m, n>`)

Sample Code:

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>

int main()
{
    cv::Mat image(cv::Mat::eye(10, 10, CV_8UC1) * 255);

    cv::Mat2f lines2;
    cv::HoughLines(image, lines2, 1, CV_PI / 180, 4); // runs the actual detection
    std::cout << lines2 << "\n";

    cv::Mat3f lines3;;
    cv::HoughLines(image, lines3, 1, CV_PI / 180, 4); // runs the actual detection
    std::cout << lines3 << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Console Output:

```
[0, 2.3212879;
 1, 2.2340214;
 -1, 2.4609141]
[0, 2.3212879, 10;
 1, 2.2340214, 6;
 -1, 2.4609141, 6]
```

---

## How the Python Wrapper Works

Let's look at the autogenerated code wrapping the `HoughLines` function:

```
static PyObject* pyopencv_cv_HoughLines(PyObject* , PyObject* args, PyObject* kw)
{
    using namespace cv;

    {
    PyObject* pyobj_image = NULL;
    Mat image;
    PyObject* pyobj_lines = NULL;
    Mat lines;
    double rho=0;
    double theta=0;
    int threshold=0;
    double srn=0;
    double stn=0;
    double min_theta=0;
    double max_theta=CV_PI;

    const char* keywords[] = { "image", "rho", "theta", "threshold", "lines", "srn", "stn", "min_theta", "max_theta", NULL };
    if( PyArg_ParseTupleAndKeywords(args, kw, "Oddi|Odddd:HoughLines", (char**)keywords, &pyobj_image, &rho, &theta, &threshold, &pyobj_lines, &srn, &stn, &min_theta, &max_theta) &&
        pyopencv_to(pyobj_image, image, ArgInfo("image", 0)) &&
        pyopencv_to(pyobj_lines, lines, ArgInfo("lines", 1)) )
    {
        ERRWRAP2(cv::HoughLines(image, lines, rho, theta, threshold, srn, stn, min_theta, max_theta));
        return pyopencv_from(lines);
    }
    }
    PyErr_Clear();

    // Similar snippet handling UMat...

    return NULL;
}
```

To summarize this, it tries to convert the object passed in the `lines` parameter to a `cv::Mat`, and then it calls `cv::HoughLines` with the `cv::Mat` as the output parameter. (If this fails, then it tries the same thing with `cv::UMat`) Unfortunately, this means that there is no way to give `cv::HoughLines` a fixed type `lines`, so as of 3.4.3 this functionality is inaccessible from Python.

---

## Solutions

The only solutions, as far as I can see, involve modifying the OpenCV source code, and rebuilding.

### Quick Hack

This is trivial, edit the [implementation of `cv::HoughLines`](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/9787ab598b6609a6ca6652a12441d741cb15f695/modules/imgproc/src/hough.cpp#L900) and change the default type to be `CV_32FC3`:

```
int type = CV_32FC3;
```

However this means that you will always get the votes (which also means that the OpenCL optimization, if present, won't get used).

### Better Patch

Add an optional boolean parameter `return_votes` with default value `false`. Modify the code such that when `return_votes` is `true`, the `type` is forced to `CV_32FC3`.

[Header](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/90f47eb952749b73c28ca7149fdd0c0cfd2b202d/modules/imgproc/include/opencv2/imgproc.hpp#L2008):

```
CV_EXPORTS_W void HoughLines( InputArray image, OutputArray lines,
                              double rho, double theta, int threshold,
                              double srn = 0, double stn = 0,
                              double min_theta = 0, double max_theta = CV_PI,
                              bool return_votes = false );
```

[Implementation](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/9787ab598b6609a6ca6652a12441d741cb15f695/modules/imgproc/src/hough.cpp#L894):

```
void HoughLines( InputArray _image, OutputArray lines,
                 double rho, double theta, int threshold,
                 double srn, double stn, double min_theta, double max_theta,
                 bool return_votes )
{
    CV_INSTRUMENT_REGION()

    int type = CV_32FC2;
    if (return_votes)
    {
         type = CV_32FC3;
    }
    else if (lines.fixedType())
    {
        type = lines.type();
        CV_CheckType(type, type == CV_32FC2 || type == CV_32FC3, "Wrong type of output lines");
    }
    // the rest...
```

Comment: Thank you for the comprehensive answer. Is it intended for such functionality to be inaccessible from python or could this be considered a bug in either the bindings or the original source code?

Comment: @user2246166 My guess would be that it's an oversight, but to make sure, I asked in the related [issue](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/pull/11108).

Answer (score 4):

There is a new python binding (opencv 4.5.1)

doc : [cv.HoughLinesWithAccumulator](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d2/d75/namespacecv.html#a1d6b9c3e48ec579faff9d838cba08e94)